# @TestPropertySource windows and linux file separator

Tags: java, spring, junit, system-variable

I have a JUnit test class starting with this declaration

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = { 
        "cache.working.dir=./src/test/resources/cacheDirRepository/" } )
```

How can I launch this test class on a *linux* based file separator system as well ('/') as on a *Windows* base file separator system ('\') ?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: Is there any problem with `/`? Should work fine everywhere, actually

Comment: No.  It's not working on a  **native** windows platform. 
A possible workaround is to start a linux command interpreter. But I am looking for a pure Windows solution. I would like to execute a `init.bat`, and not a `init.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following

// Platform independent and safe to use across Linux and Windows

```
"cache.working.dir=."+File.separator+"src"+File.separator+"test"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"cacheDirRepository"
```

Comment: Yes. This solution is working, but if you have multiple similar test cases, it's a real job to transform all test cases.

Comment: Yes but you can create generic path by creating a method

java.util.List pathParts = java.util.Arrays.asList("test", "resources", "cacheDirRepository");
genPath = StringUtils.join(pathParts, File.separator);

Comment: You cannot use StringUtils static functions inside an annotation declaration. You'll get the error :
`The value for annotation attribute TestPropertySource.properties must be a constant expression`

Comment: I cannot use as well File.separator... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I share my last solution. May-be there's one smarter. And I'll be pleased to learn...

3 actions :

1. I'll use placeholders to process my annotation at runtime.
   The declaration of my annotation is parameterized with a *file separator placeholder*.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "cache.working.dir=." + 
                                        "${file_separator}" + "src" +
                                        "${file_separator}" + "test" + 
                                        "${file_separator}" + "resources" + 
                                        "${file_separator}" + "cacheDirRepository" + 
                                        "${file_separator}", ...
```

2. I declare a specific bean in my container to process these placeholders.

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

3. Finally, I pass my os-dependent file separator char at runtime as a JVM parameter

For Unix/MacOsX

```
mvn clean install -DargLine="-Dfile_separator=/"
```

For Windows

```
mvn clean install -DargLine="-Dfile_separator=\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `java.io.File` package have some variables for this, you can use them to resolve it:

```
File.separator // use '/' in linux and '\' in windows
File.separatorChar // use '/' in linux and '\' in windows
File.pathSeparator // use ':' in linux and ';' in windows
File.pathSeparatorChar // use ':' in linux and ';' in windows
```